# What is the difference between a vector and a representation of a vector in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, vectors, representation-theory

What does the phrase

> *The wave function is a representation of the abstract quantum state.*

Or more generally,

> *$A$ is a representation of a vector $\vec V $*

mean?

What is the difference between a vector and a representation of a vector?

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: @BioPhysicist The First one is from *Quantum Mechanics: A Paradigms Approach* by David H. McIntyre. The second one is made by me, based on other references that I have seen in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The state vector $|\Psi\rangle$ "encodes" everything about a quantum state, because you can choose to expand $|\Psi\rangle$ in any orthonormal, complete basis corresponding to some observable $A$ with eigenstates $|a_n\rangle$:

$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_n|a_n\rangle\langle a_n|\Psi\rangle$$

Note that for each term we have a "component" $\langle a_n|\Psi\rangle$ for the basis vector $|a_n\rangle$. In quantum mechanics, the probability that a measurement of $A$ on the state will return a value of $a_n$ is given by $|\langle a_n|\Psi\rangle|^2$

It is useful to compare this to vectors one usually sees in introductory physics or math courses. For example, we can describe a force vector in various bases, such as the usual "x and y": $\mathbf F=F_x\hat i+F_y\hat j$, along and perpendicular to an incline: $\mathbf=F_\parallel\hat e_\parallel+F_\bot\hat e_\bot$, etc. With any basis choice your vector has "components" corresponding to each basis vector. When we add each component multiplied by its corresponding basis vector, we end up with the entire vector. The vector by itself without a reference to a basis is not too helpful.

This is why the state vector is "abstract" and represents the quantum state. $|\Psi\rangle$ by itself isn't something we can work with, but by projecting it onto some basis that represents an observable we can determine how likely it is that a measurement of the observable associated with that basis will return a particular value.

Comment: I think when we talk about "wave function", we usually refer to $\langle x| \Psi \rangle$ or some other representation like this, rather than $| \Psi \rangle$.

Comment: @Errorbar Yes I agree. I changed it to "state vector"

Comment: This does make sense, but what about basis themselves? They are also a subset of the abstract vector space, so doesn't your argument becomes circular?

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist You can still express the basis vectors in other bases; either their own or others. For example, in many introductory text one determines energy eigenstates in the position basis for things like the infinite potential well, harmonic oscillator, and hydrogen atom.